# C++ boolalpha confusion

Tags: c++

Hi anyone can explain the following c++ code result?

```
input: true false 1
output: false, true, true,

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    bool c1, c2, c3;
    cin >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
    cout << boolalpha << c1 << ", " << c2 << ", " << c3 << ", " << endl;//LINE I
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha)

Comment: Downvote for zero effort.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha)

- Enables the boolalpha flag in the stream str as if by calling str.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha

Always check the documentation first.

Answer (score 2):

The `istream` object you operate on (`cin` here) expects either 0 or 1 for input to the `bool`, your input gave it `true`.  This causes the operation to fail, and the `failbit` to be set on the `istream`, since you don't check for input failing, the next two assignments to `c2` and `c3` does happen, and is instead skipped.  Thus, `c1` is false, as the input operation failed.  `c2` and `c3` was not modified nor initialized, and thus could have any value.